# jdk1.6.0_161 supports AES/GCM/NoPadding Cipher?

Tags: java, encryption, aes-gcm

I have read multiple questions regarding same issue, but the Java version were different. I got the idea about how it can be enabled in Java 7 and 8. But unfortunately, I am willing to enable it in Java 6.

Already tried to replace the policy jar as suggested in this - https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html. But this doesn't help.

My client has enabled this GCM Cipher and I have CBC enabled for my application.

I have a simple question - is it possible to enable GCM for Java 6 with TLS 1.2? If yes, then how?

Error:

```
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:                                                                     3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [na:1.6.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [na:1.6.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206) [na:1.6.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:905) [na:1.6.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:928) [na:1.6.0_161]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682) [na:1.6.0_161]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

I would request to not mark it as duplicate and downgrade, as this is related to specific version of Java. Other question do answer for other versions, but that do not solve my issue.

Comment: First, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48934806/5221149) for how to check if the ciphersuite is even supported by your Java version. If not, then you'd need a third-party library to support it, e.g. [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html). If it is supported, but not enabled, do a web search to find out how to enable it in Java 6.

Comment: See also: [How to use TLS 1.2 in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33364100/5221149)

Comment: As I am using 161, so TLS 1.2 is not a problem here. List of supported Ciphers doesn't contain GCM. So, I guess BouncyCastle is the only option left.

Comment: Java 6 has been EOL for seven years. Why are you still developing new code for it?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I agree with your point. My application will sun set in next few months and I have migrated to Java 8 for new application. But I have to support client for these few months, until they completely move to my new application.

Comment: @Bhakt cant blame you i've been there.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam did you used BouncyCastel in past?